# How do I fix a Windows 7 that fails just before showing the login screen?

Tags: windows-7, boot, hard-drive-failure

The laptop won't start after trying to install a virtual machine. It will show the windows logo and fails just before showing the logon screen? How do I fix this.

EDIT:

My computer gives me the options to `start normally` which doesn't start the computer and `open startup repair` which ends up in a blank screen. Upon clicking the `Start Normally` windows logo appears but the startup fails before the login screen.

The problem is I don't have the installation disk( Windows).

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. You haven't given very much detail for anyone to really help you. Please [edit] your question to provide more details of what happens when it `fails`. Any error messages or specific behavior is helpful.

Comment: Did you try safe mode?

Comment: My guess you need to repair your installation.  There are hundreds if not thousands of articles online that describe how this can be done.  All it requires is a Windows 7 media.

Comment: @Ramhound `Windows 7 media`?

Comment: Why would anyone give this question a -1?

Answer (score 0):

On start up, press F8 (or F7 if F8 fails) and select Use Last Known Good Configuration - we'll see if that helps.

Comment: Both keys don't appear to work. Please view my edit.